# Invalid Argument error when using jQuery template (tmpl) plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using the jQuery tmpl plugin to generate some HTML for a bunch of objects in an array, and I'm getting an Invalid Argument error within the core jQuery library when I try to template a large number of objects, for example: in some cases the array might have over 9000 objects in the array and I'll get the error.  This is a .NET 4.0 app with a bunch of client-side code, the exact error reported by visual studio is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument." and it is occurring at line 679 (in the merge function) of the un-minified jQuery library, 1.8.2 .  I'm trying to generate the HTML so I can do some other formatting on it and display only certain things at a time.  This won't happen if I template fewer objects, such as 4000 or less.  I don't know exactly where the cutoff is.  Has anyone run into this before, or know if there's a workaround?

tmpl plugin version: 1.0.0pre
jQuery core version: 1.8.2

Thanks.

Comment: Use the browser's JS console to help pinpoint the error, there is not enough information for anyone to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you got this error because on you local machine, your Javascript doesnt work with such a big object. As i know it doesnt depend on verstion plugin and so on - solution more deeper in core. So size of your array with 9000 object bigger that size which can be processed.